# How to run a Dart scratch file? There does not seem to be an option to run

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 3.2

File > New > Scratch File
This created a new file, scratch.dart

I entered some simple Dart code.

```
void main() { print('This is the output'); }
```

How do I run this code? I've searched around the IDE and cannot find anything. What is the purpose of the scratch file if I cannot run test (Dart) code in it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create the scratch.dart file directly under the project folder. Soon as you write some code in the file, you should see the option to Run scratch.dart on right-clicking the file. The option to run doesn't appear until you write some code.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me. The default location for scratch files is usually at the same level of your project folder. Look for Scratches and Consoles > Scratches. Then you can drag it into your project folder. It doesn't have to be in /lib either.

Comment: that's not how it's supposed to be done. How to run the scratch file within Scratches and Consoles ? I can run java code there but not Dart.